# Language Processing - Using R or Python?

Tags: python, r, text

I am interested in doing natural language processing.  Probably begin with examining the tone of text (perhaps using the Harvard IV-4 dictionary).  Later on, maybe move to working with topic models.

I am a lot better at R than Python, but I have recently done some web-scraping with Python.

How do I get started?

Comment: In general, write code in a language that you are more comfortable with so that you're hard work doesn't turn into an unmanageable jumbled mess.

Comment: Nominating to reopen since reworded to fit rules in the help center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is well known for Natural Language Processing.

See the NLTK: http://nltk.org/

Quick demo from the home page:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> sentence = """At eight o'clock on Thursday morning
... Arthur didn't feel very good."""
>>> tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
>>> tokens
['At', 'eight', "o'clock", 'on', 'Thursday', 'morning',
'Arthur', 'did', "n't", 'feel', 'very', 'good', '.']
>>> tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
>>> tagged[0:6]
[('At', 'IN'), ('eight', 'CD'), ("o'clock", 'JJ'), ('on', 'IN'),
('Thursday', 'NNP'), ('morning', 'NN')]
```

I think that's enough to get you started!

Answer (score 2):

I personally don't know R very well. However, I can recommend you take a look at [this](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html) CRAN page specific to NLP. In fact, R has bindings to [Apache OpenNLP](http://opennlp.apache.org/) through the *openNLP* package.

You should always use a language you are comfortable with to avoid excess development time (mostly overhead to learn a new language) and hair-tearing out on your part. You should use R. I know Python so I would probably use that. Really, **it's up to you...**